# Is using a / within a character class in a regex literal always safe?

Tags: javascript, regex

When using a regex literal in JavaScript it's `/`-delimited, e.g. `/^[a-z]$/`.

When including a slash in that regex, i.e. `/^[a-z/]$/`, everything seems to work fine - both my IDE's syntax highlighter and the JS parsers of Firefox and Chrome accept it.

Is it standardized behavior that `/` does not need to be escaped within a character class or just a developer-friendly implementation and thus not work in all browsers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is defined by [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (p. 25):

> *RegularExpressionClass* **`::`**
>     **`[`** *RegularExpressionClassChars* **`]`**
>
> *RegularExpressionClassChars* **`::`**
>     [empty]
>     *RegularExpressionClassChars*  *RegularExpressionClassChar*
>
> *RegularExpressionClassChar* **`::`**
>     *RegularExpressionNonTerminator* **but not one of `]` or `\`**
>     *RegularExpressionBackslashSequence*
>
> *RegularExpressionNonTerminator* **`::`**
>     *SourceCharacter* **but not** *LineTerminator*

In contrast, the normal *RegularExpressionChar* is defined as:

> RegularExpressionChar **`::`**
>     *RegularExpressionNonTerminator* **but not one of `\` or `/` or `[`**
>     *RegularExpressionBackslashSequence*
>     *RegularExpressionClass*

So within character classes you can use `/` freely without the need for escaping.